# Detecting operation changes in GitPython

Tags: python, gitpython

GitPython provides an interface for asynchronously notifying of operation progress called [RemoteProgress](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/a8591a094a768d73e6efb5a698f74d354c989291/git/util.py#L350).

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out when the different operations (`op_code`s) begin and end. The library seems to have these `BEGIN` and `END` flags, but they never seem to be set.

In [`update()`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/a8591a094a768d73e6efb5a698f74d354c989291/git/util.py#L493), how do I detect begin and end of the different Git operations?